# Message does not contain valid HTTP context information, Need return context info

Tags: json, web-services, http, http-headers, websphere

I am using IBM integration toolkit

I have an application with two flows; the request flow has a json request message using http request node then the message is thrown to another flow (in another application representing a stub)through a MQ Input, compute node then MQ reply.

It then throws the message to the response flow in my application through MQ Input

I need to output the message in a json form through http reply node but in the flow it runs an exception "Message does not contain valid HTTP context information, Need return context info"

if anyone have a clue for this error and how to solve it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your HTTP response flow does not know which request it has to respond.

In case you really need your request and response to be implemented as different flows, you have to store identifier of incoming HTTP or SOAP request somewhere, for example as a message in some dedicated queue.

In your request flow you can find identifier of request in

```
 InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestIdentifier
```

or

```
 InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.RequestIdentifier
```

depending on the type of your input node.

Then, your response flow should read a message written by request flow to find a value of RequestIdentifier.
This value should be set into the LocalEnvironment of response message assembly:

```
OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.Reply.ReplyIdentifier
```

or

```
OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.Reply.ReplyIdentifier
```

Here is IBM doc: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac20450_.htm#ac20450___le

> When the HTTPInput node receives an input request message, it sets the local environment field Destination.HTTP.RequestIdentifier to a unique value that identifies the Web service client that sent the request. You can refer to this value, and you can save it to another location if appropriate.
>
> For example, if you design a pair of message flows that interact with
>   an existing WebSphere MQ application (as described in Broker calls
>   existing Web service), you can save the identifier value in the
>   request flow, and restore it in the reply flow, to ensure that the
>   correct client receives the reply. If you use this technique, you must
>   not change the data, and you must retain the data as a BLOB.
>
> The HTTPReply node extracts the identifier value from the local
>   environment tree and sets up the reply so that it is sent to the
>   specific client. However, if you are using an HTTPReply node in a flow
>   that does not have an HTTPInput node, and this field has been deleted
>   or set incorrectly, message BIP3143S is issued.

Comment: Thaanks very much